# use the pc-ble-driver in python3

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, access-violation, exit-code

I'm want to use the pc-ble-driver in python3

So downloaded and compiled [jorgenmk's pc-ble-driver-py](https://github.com/jorgenmk/pc-ble-driver-py).

I executed the sample code for test with compile result

An error such as "process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" was occured while running the sample code.

Please tell me why this error occurs. And what I did wrong in the compile process.

The compilation environment is as follows.

- Boost 1.61
- CMake 3.4.3
- SWIG 2.0.12
- Python 3.6.4
- Visual Studio 2015

created the Boost1.61 library using the following command:

```
...\boost_1_61_0> bootstrap.bat
...\boost_1_61_0> b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=32 link=static --with-thread --with-system --with-regex --with-date_time --with-chrono
```

command result:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

...\boost_1_61_0

    The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

...\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib
```

create the visual studio project using the following command:

```
...\pc-ble-driver-py> cmake -G "Visual Studio 14" -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=...\Python\Python36-32\Libs\python36.lib
```

created pc-ble-driver-py library using following command:

```
...\pc-ble-driver-py> msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

---

- When using cmake, the python path was set as the 2.7 version path, so I set the path directly to the 3.6 version.
- A warning is generate when using msbuild. warning is "warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (949)."